# Lightweight audio playback and image display for Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, audio, raspberry-pi

I'm creating a server application for a Raspberry Pi and the task is to accept incoming commands through a network socket and then display an image together with a short audio file (300-500ms).

The most important thing is performance, since there will be customers waiting for a response to their action (which triggers the incoming socket command).

So I'm looking for some recommendation for simple lightweight audio library and also a image viewer library which preferably can be used in Python. The image library should be able to cache the image in RAM so the script does not need to read from memory card each time an image is to be displayed.

I have not decided which Linux distribution to use but I guess Arch Linux (no Xorg) will yield more available resources to my Python script.

Comment: look for gstreamer, it has python bindings I think

Comment: try http://processing.org framework.

Comment: Maybe there is a really lightweight Window-manager which only starts my Python script in fullscreen...

Comment: @DimitryK Unfortunately, from my experience Processing isn't the best choice on Raspberry PI: it needs a bit of tweaking to install and then it's slow to compile and run. For quick prototyping Python does the job. For 'heavy-lifting' openFrameworks performs beautifully, the only downside is the compile time (or at least the initial compilation of the main library)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza when you use Processing PDE on RP, it's true it compiles slowly. However you can develop sketch on your own machine, and then just RUN it on RP using `processing-java` command line version of the executable. If you use native rendering modes (the ones which use GPU) like P3D or P2D  (as opposed to default JAVA2D renderer which doens't use GPU capabilities), you should see good performance.

Comment: @DimitryK Cool, I'll try the P3D renderer again. Perhaps either a shared RPi folder to compile Processing sketches into .jar files and perhaps triggering the host PC compilation of the .jar from RPi might be a workaround.

Comment: Hope it works for you. If you need info on how to run `processing-java` then this video (which I made earlier) may help. http://youtu.be/S1Nf9mP-h8Q?t=5m43s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the server/rpi will have the images and audio files will already be on the server and your python script will just wait for cues on the network to display a certain image and playback a certain audio file.

I imagine Python is installed already and you might actually have [pygame](http://pygame.org/) ready too.
PyGame is easy to pickup and it will make it easier to load images and sounds and render them. Since you're listening to network events you should probably use a thread for keep the gui(images/sound) thread separate and responsive.

Here's a very minimal example on how to load an audio file and play it back:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
#init game engine with audio
pygame.init()           
pygame.mixer.init()
#load a sound
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("/path/to/WAVS/sample.wav")
#playback
sound.play()
```

Note that pygame supports multiple audio formats. With wav file, it seems to like [signed wav files](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9541/issues-playing-back-wav-files-with-pygame/9819#9819).

Comment: Thanks, we are currently testing with pygame and it will probably work as long as pictures are cached in RAM. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think the images will be cached in ram if you load them at the start of your application. It sounds just a tad similar to what I've done for the [JoyJacket project](http://www.hirschandmann.com/2013/cadbury-joy-jackets/), only I had a separate thread for the GPIO/serial communication rather than a networked message, so had a main thread which handled pygame but also had another thread (using composition had a class solely responsible for GPIO) doing serial so I wouldn't block screen or audio rendering